# Why are there multiple versions of "Phone" installed under all apps in Android Lollipop?

Tags: applications, stock-android

Why are there multiple versions of "Phone" installed under ALL apps on my Android Lollipop 5.1.1 phone?

Menu = Settings → Apps → ALL

There are three versions of "Phone":

- Phone - `com.android.server.telecom`
- Phone - `com.android.phone`
- Phone/Messaging Storage - `com.android.providers.telephony`

Comment: There was a mistake in my last (now deleted) comment. Sorry for wrong info.

Comment: not a problem - a little research suggests that *com.android.server.telecom* supercedes *com.android.phone* but they're both running concurrently on my phone (as "Phone"). *com.android.phone* is giving me a spurious voicemail message "New Voicemail (255)" everytime I start the phone. And runs as a separate process to the other - so I'd like to delete it, but am nervous over any side effects...

Comment: Do you have root access? A normal user cannot remove a system app and Disable option is greyed out for them.

Comment: I've managed to clear the phantom voicemail (just needed to leave another voicemail and delete). But I'm still interested in why there are two "Phone" apps running concurrently on the phone (notwithstanding that the packages aren't actually the same) - so I'll leave the Q open for a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Phone/Messaging Storage - com.android.providers.telephony**

The Telephony provider contains data related to phone operation, specifically SMS and MMS messages and access to the APN list, including the MMSC to use.

**Phone - com.android.server.telecom**

**Phone - com.android.phone**

The package name has been changed from "com.android.phone" to "com.android.server.telecom" on some devices ( ex. Nexus 5 with Android 5.0 )

But for some reason you have both the packages. They are probably different apps and should not cause you any trouble.

Comment: The point is to find out what's that "*some reason*". OP already figured most of the stuff, see his comments. Thanks though, for posting the answer here.

Comment: @Firelord Most possibly due to an update. but it actually depends on the phone

Answer (score 3):

These are not different **versions**, these are different **apps**. An app can have any name regardless of other apps' names. It is possible to have hundreds of apps with the same name on one phone because the name you see as a user has nothing to do with the name which sees Android (for example the system name for Shazam is `com.shazam.android`).

I have two "Camera" in my phone. One was pre-installed and the second is Google Camera whose visible name is also "Camera".