# How to remove the icon, caused by a voicemail, from Status bar?

Tags: notification-icons, voicemail

I have a Sprint Nexus 6 running Android 5.1.1.

The icon that I see in my Status bar when I receive a voicemail does not swipe away. It remains in my Status bar even after I listen to the message and delete it.

The only solution that I have found for this is to reboot the phone. Is there another way around this?

Comment: What happens when you force-stop the app which is causing that icon in status bar or go to Settings -> Apps -> All apps -> *your app* -> uncheck "Show notifications" -> check "Show Notifications"?

Comment: @Firelord I can't I don't have a voicemail app I just use Google Dialer v2.1 and I can't do the can't change those settings via the path you posted.

Comment: @Firelord I see the notification comes from "Phone" so I go into "Settings -> Apps -> All" and there are 3 "Phone" apps and one "Phone/Messaging Storage". I force-closed the middle one and the app went away, but now I'm confused as to why there are 3 apps in here of the same name. Do you know anything about that? Also thank you for helping me.

Comment: See [why are there multiple versions of "Phone" installed under all apps on my android lollipop 5.1.1 phone?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/125432) Order of reading: Read the comments on the question followed by the answers.

Comment: @KazRodgers, where you able to find a soultion? This VoiceMail drives me crazy too:)

Comment: Yeah do long press on the icon, go into settings and remove notifications once you close the menu and swipe up the notification should be gone. This works on nougat. I can't speak for 5.1.1 though. Try out firelords solution below for that. It worked back then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This is an app independent answer.

For cases where an icon seems to be stuck in the Status bar, choose any of the following approach:

#### Force-stop the app

1. Find the app causing that icon.

   Usually, it is easy to know just by looking at the icon and matching it with app icons under Settings -> Apps -> All apps. For some exceptional cases, you can use apps like [Notification Saver](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pghant.notifsaver) or [Notification History](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tiger.workshop.notificationhistory) or setup [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) in PC and use the command:

   ```
   adb shell dumpsys notification
   ```

   Single out your notification and look for the package name of the app behind that icon. Read [View app's full package name?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/28767/96277) to get the label for the app from the package name.

   *Assumption*: The app causing the issue is "AppX".
2. Go to Settings -> Apps -> All apps -> AppX -> Force-stop.

That should remove the icon from the Status bar.

#### Uncheck Notifications

1. Find the app causing that icon.
2. Go to Settings -> Apps -> All apps -> AppX -> uncheck Show notifications -> check Show notifications.

Works well for user installed third-party apps.

There may be apps where  the option **Force stop** or/and **Show notifications** would be greyed out. For such apps, only the mighty root can help. Any app having root privileges should be able kill such apps, such as [OS Monitor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eolwral.osmonitor). For example, in [Terminal Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm) you can kill an app using its package name and `am`:

```
su
am force-stop PACKAGE_NAME_OF_APP
```

Related readings:

- ["Show notifications" is greyed out for some apps. What's causing it and how do I change it?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/120169/show-notifications-is-greyed-out-for-some-apps-whats-causing-it-and-how-do-i)
- [I've rooted my phone.  Now what?  What do I gain from rooting?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/1/96277)

Answer (score 0):

Open 'Jio4GVoice' app > Open Settings(3 dots on the top of the Jio4GVoice app) > Select 'Settings' > Select 'Notofications' > Untick 'Show app status in the notification bar'.